# Copy image region to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two elements: `<div>` (size matching browser viewport, but there is overflowing content; its content and background image can be dragged by user) and `<canvas>` (size matches viewport).

I want to give user ability to change background of `div` using canvas. How can I copy appropriate region of div background (which is data URL saved in `style` attribute) to canvas and then backwards?

```
<div style="background:url(data:image/png;base64,...); width:100vw; height:100vh">
  <!-- The div's background can be dragged by user-->

  <!-- Canvas can containe only part of div's bg -->
  <canvas style="width:100vw; height:100vh"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a snippet please?

Comment: @edkeveked i have just added it

Comment: You can use vars to track the offset values caused by the User drag/change. Then maybe use an `image` element as [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) that you could feed to `canvas` `drawImage()` along with those offset values to tell the canvas what part of the image to actually show.